# Stop blue dots from appearing next to updated apps?

Tags: iphone, ios

When apps get updated, little blue dots appear next to the app name in iOS 8.1 (and some earlier versions as well).  This is just a pet peeve, but those blue dots annoy me.  For example, if I update 10 apps, I have to open each of those ten apps to make the blue dots go away, which is a pain.

Is there any way to disable the blue dots so they don't appear for new/updated apps?

Comment: Over 19000 views and only 2 upvotes. Lurk much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There currently is no way for you to disable this as of <=iOS8 and within the boundaries of factory OS. This is a visual aide for those people that have automatic updates enabled. You can look into jailbreaking your device if it is worth that much to you

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion.  For completeness, if I were to jailbreak my device, any ideas on how I would then go about disabling the blue dots?  I've been considering jailbreaking my device for other reasons, so this adds one more reason to the list...

Comment: @davewy oh I'm sure there are options out there. I jailbroke device before iOS6 and Cydia seemed to be the leading agency then feels like it now. They have themes and customization like 'active wallpapers that play gifs' so I'm sure little blue dots aren't that arduous to get rid of. This is all speculation of course. Jailbroken is s powerful tool in altering private APIs so you would just have to search through the Cydia App Store or theme customization options they offer. I'm willing to bet someone has done it but personally can't say since I haven't researched it since iOS6

Comment: In fact I kind of feel like that's where Apple got the slide up to reveal settings feature to quickly turn on/off Bluetooth wifi etc. it was in jail broken devices long before Apple implemented. Lots of creative people out there

Comment: In case anyone is curious: the (free) NoNewMark package in Cydia successfully removes this annoyance!